# Performance of a java application rendering video files

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, networking, load, mp4

I have a java/j2ee application deployed in tomcat container on a windows server. The application is a training portal where the training files such as pdf/ppt/flash/mp4 files are read from a share path. When the user clicks a training link, the associated file from the share folder is read downloaded from the share path to the client machine and start running.
If the user clicks mp4/flash/pdf files, it is taking too much time to get opened.
Is there anything in the application level, we need to configure? or it is a configuration for load in the server? or is it something needs attention from a WAN settings?
I am unable to find out a solution for this issue?
Please post your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure because there is not so much details, but I'm 90% sure that the application code is not the main problem.

For example:

> If the user clicks mp4/flash/pdf files, it is taking too much time to get opened.

A PDF is basically just a string. Flash is a client-side technology. And I'm pretty sure that you just send a stream to a video player in order to play a MP4. So the server is supposed to just take the file and send it. The server is probably not the source of your problem if we assume that he can handle the number of requests.

So it's about your network: it is too slow for some reasons. And it's difficult to be more specific without more details.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I am also suspecting like that. But the network team is completely denying the performance of the server. They are sure that the network load on the server is pretty fine. We are now checking whether the files accessed from the various countries across the globe may the reason and the server resides in one particular region

Comment: The further the data is, the slower it loads. You can maybe check the max speed between your computer and the server and compare it to the max speed between your computer and an online speed test.